# python numpy roll with padding

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to roll a 2D numpy array, except that I'd like to fill the ends with zeros rather than roll the data as if it were periodic.

The following

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

np.roll(x, 1, axis=1)
```

returns

```
array([[3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 5]])
```

but what I would prefer is

```
array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think that you are going to find an easier way to do this that is built-in. The touch-up seems quite simple to me:

```
y = np.roll(x,1,axis=1)
y[:,0] = 0
```

If you want this to be more direct then maybe you could copy the roll function to a new function and change it to do what you want. The roll() function is in the `site-packages\core\numeric.py` file.

Comment: I was hoping to do this in one line, since I need to do this multiple times in different directions and I can't clobber y, but your suggestion is probably the best solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. And I think np.roll should do it natively with a keyword argument. np.pad does not accept negative values and it is anyway changing the shape of the array which is overkill to me.

Answer (score 55):

[`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) can be used to create an array with surrounding zeros. Pad seems to be quite powerful and can do much more than a simple "roll". The tuple `((0,0),(1,0))` used in this answer indicates the "side" of the matrix which to pad.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

print np.pad(x,((0,0),(1,0)), mode='constant')[:, :-1]
```

Giving

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 4 5]]
```

Comment: If it isn't obvious, here's shifting 5 elements: print np.pad(x,((0,0),(5,0)), mode='constant')[:, :-5]

Comment: Note that `np.roll` will allow for negative values, but `np.pad` will give you `ValueError: cannot contain negative values` if you try to send it negative rolls.  So the functionality is not quite the same.

Comment: @sh37211 for "negative" shift :`np.pad(x,((0,0),(0,1)), mode='constant')[:, 1:])`

Answer (score 7):

I just wrote the following. It could be more optimized by avoiding `zeros_like` and just computing the shape for `zeros` directly.

```
import numpy as np
def roll_zeropad(a, shift, axis=None):
    """
    Roll array elements along a given axis.

    Elements off the end of the array are treated as zeros.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input array.
    shift : int
        The number of places by which elements are shifted.
    axis : int, optional
        The axis along which elements are shifted.  By default, the array
        is flattened before shifting, after which the original
        shape is restored.

    Returns
    -------
    res : ndarray
        Output array, with the same shape as `a`.

    See Also
    --------
    roll     : Elements that roll off one end come back on the other.
    rollaxis : Roll the specified axis backwards, until it lies in a
               given position.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> x = np.arange(10)
    >>> roll_zeropad(x, 2)
    array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x, -2)
    array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0])

    >>> x2 = np.reshape(x, (2,5))
    >>> x2
    array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, 1)
    array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, -2)
    array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9, 0, 0]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, 1, axis=0)
    array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, -1, axis=0)
    array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, 1, axis=1)
    array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, -2, axis=1)
    array([[2, 3, 4, 0, 0],
           [7, 8, 9, 0, 0]])

    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, 50)
    array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, -50)
    array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
    >>> roll_zeropad(x2, 0)
    array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

    """
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    if shift == 0: return a
    if axis is None:
        n = a.size
        reshape = True
    else:
        n = a.shape[axis]
        reshape = False
    if np.abs(shift) > n:
        res = np.zeros_like(a)
    elif shift < 0:
        shift += n
        zeros = np.zeros_like(a.take(np.arange(n-shift), axis))
        res = np.concatenate((a.take(np.arange(n-shift,n), axis), zeros), axis)
    else:
        zeros = np.zeros_like(a.take(np.arange(n-shift,n), axis))
        res = np.concatenate((zeros, a.take(np.arange(n-shift), axis)), axis)
    if reshape:
        return res.reshape(a.shape)
    else:
        return res
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it could be useful. However, I'm playing around a bit with your suggestion, and it seems to be slower than Justin's original suggestion by about a factor of two (1.8sec vs 0.8sec on a random (1e4 x 1e4) array, according to cProfile). It looks like the concatenate calls are causing the double execution time.

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np

def shift_2d_replace(data, dx, dy, constant=False):
    """
    Shifts the array in two dimensions while setting rolled values to constant
    :param data: The 2d numpy array to be shifted
    :param dx: The shift in x
    :param dy: The shift in y
    :param constant: The constant to replace rolled values with
    :return: The shifted array with "constant" where roll occurs
    """
    shifted_data = np.roll(data, dx, axis=1)
    if dx < 0:
        shifted_data[:, dx:] = constant
    elif dx > 0:
        shifted_data[:, 0:dx] = constant

    shifted_data = np.roll(shifted_data, dy, axis=0)
    if dy < 0:
        shifted_data[dy:, :] = constant
    elif dy > 0:
        shifted_data[0:dy, :] = constant
    return shifted_data
```

This function would work on 2D arrays and replace rolled values with a constant of your choosing.

Comment: Looks useful. But if dx is positive, why call `np.abs(dx)`? Isn't that the same as just dx?

Comment: Good point. Don't need it especially with the if statement there. I'm just paranoid. :]

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but feels like a quick way to do what you want in one line. Perhaps would work best if wrapped inside a smart function (example below provided just for horizontal axis):

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)  # an example 2D array

print a

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

shift = 1
a = numpy.hstack((numpy.zeros((a.shape[0], shift)), a[:,:-shift]))

print a

[[0 1 2]
 [0 4 5]
 [0 7 8]]
```

Comment: A word of caution: this does not work with `shift = 0`, because of the `a[:,:-shift]`. This can matter if the shifting procedure is put in a general function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`ndimage.shift`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.shift.html):

```
>>> from scipy import ndimage
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> ndimage.shift(arr, (0,1))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the answer by Hooked (since it took me a few minutes to understand it)

The code below first pads a certain amount of zeros in the up, down, left and right margins and then selects the original matrix inside the padded one. A perfectly useless code, but good for understanding `np.pad`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
y = np.pad(x,((1,3),(2,4)), mode='constant')[1:-3,2:-4]

print np.all(x==y)
```

now to make an upwards shift of 2 combined with a rightwards shift of 1 position one should do

```
print np.pad(x,((0,2),(1,0)), mode='constant')[2:0,0:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use numpy's triu and scipy.linalg's circulant. Make a circulant version of your matrix. Then, select the upper triangular part starting at the first diagonal, (the default option in triu). The row index will correspond to the number of padded zeros you want.

If you don't have scipy you can generate a nXn circulant matrix by making an (n-1) X (n-1) identity matrix and stacking a row [0 0 ... 1] on top of it and the column [1 0 ... 0] to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with shifting a 2-d array in both directions

```py
def shift_frame(img,move_dir,fill=np.inf):
    frame = np.full_like(img,fill)
    x,y = move_dir
    size_x,size_y = np.array(img.shape) - np.abs(move_dir)
    frame_x = slice(0,size_x) if x>=0 else slice(-x,size_x-x)
    frame_y = slice(0,size_y) if y>=0 else slice(-y,size_y-y)
    img_x = slice(x,None) if x>=0 else slice(0,size_x)
    img_y = slice(y,None) if y>=0 else slice(0,size_y)
    frame[frame_x,frame_y] = img[img_x,img_y]
    return frame

test = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
shift_frame(test,(1,1))
'''
returns:
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, -1],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, -1],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, -1],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
'''
```

I haven't measured the runtime of this, but it seems to work well enough for my use, although a built-in one liner would be nice

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def roll_zeropad(a, dyx):
    h, w = a.shape[:2]
    dy, dx = dyx
    pad_x, start_x, end_x = ((dx,0), 0, w) if dx > 0 else ((0,-dx), -dx, w-dx)
    pad_y, start_y, end_y = ((dy,0), 0, h) if dy > 0 else ((0,-dy), -dy, h-dy)
    return np.pad(a, (pad_y, pad_x))[start_y:end_y,start_x:end_x]

test = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
out = roll_zeropad(test,(1,1))
print(out)
"""
returns:

[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  2  3]
 [ 0  5  6  7  8]
 [ 0 10 11 12 13]
 [ 0 15 16 17 18]]

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my oneliner for 1D arrays with integer shifts regardless the sign

```
x if shift == 0 else np.roll(np.pad(x,np.abs(shift)), shift)[np.abs(shift):-np.abs(shift)]
```

```
x=np.array([1,2,3,2,1])
shift=0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A generic N-d array solution for an array of arbitrary roll amounts:

```
def roll_along(arr, shifts, axis, fill_value=None):
    assert arr.ndim - 1 == shifts.ndim
    axis %= arr.ndim
    shape = (1,) * axis + (-1,) + (1,) * (arr.ndim - axis - 1)
    dim_indices = np.arange(arr.shape[axis]).reshape(shape)
    shifts_ = np.expand_dims(shifts, axis)

    if fill_value is not None:
        runs_ = -shifts_
        left_mask = (runs_ >= 0) & (dim_indices >= runs_)
        right_mask = (runs_ < 0) & (dim_indices < runs_ + arr.shape[axis])
        mask = left_mask | right_mask
        arr = np.where(mask, arr, np.full_like(arr, fill_value))

    indices = (dim_indices - shifts_) % arr.shape[axis]
    arr = np.take_along_axis(arr, indices, axis)
    return arr
```

Example usage:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(8 * 7).reshape(8, 7)
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
       [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
       [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])

>>> shifts = np.array([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> roll_along(arr, shifts, axis=-1)
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13,  7,  8,  9],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 14, 15],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 21],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [41, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
       [47, 48, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46],
       [53, 54, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52]])

>>> roll_along(arr, shifts, axis=-1, fill_value=0)
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 11, 12, 13,  0,  0,  0],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20,  0,  0],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  0],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [ 0, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
       [ 0,  0, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 49, 50, 51, 52]])
```