# python numpy roll with padding in arbitrary direction

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to re-center a set of image-like data where I know the appropriate offset in the x- and y- dimensions.  Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777907/python-numpy-roll-with-padding) question I want to do something like a "roll" but instead of assuming periodic boundary conditions I want to fill in the "empty" positions in the array with zeros.

My question is more general than the one that I have linked because I would like to shift an array in arbitrary directions. In the accepted solution, one must always know what direction the image is being rolled, in order to cut off the appropriate edge. In particular, here is the accepted solution which involves shifting the array x by 1.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

print np.pad(x,((0,0),(1,0)), mode='constant')[:, :-1]
```

However to do the reverse operation, one would have to hard code the following change:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

print np.pad(x,((0,0),(0,1)), mode='constant')[:, 1:] 
// changed argument of pad
// and array indices
```

Is there a simple way to implement both at once?

Answer (score 1):

The core of `pad` for your `mode` is:

```
newmat = narray.copy()

# API preserved, but completely new algorithm which pads by building the
# entire block to pad before/after `arr` with in one step, for each axis.
if mode == 'constant':
    for axis, ((pad_before, pad_after), (before_val, after_val)) \
            in enumerate(zip(pad_width, kwargs['constant_values'])):
        newmat = _prepend_const(newmat, pad_before, before_val, axis)
        newmat = _append_const(newmat, pad_after, after_val, axis)
```

So it's that `pad_width` tuple (of tuples) that determines the action, either prepending or appending the constant pad.  Notice that it iterates on axes.

Your own code probably will be just as fast, since `pad` isn't doing anything magical (or compiled) here.

The `prepend` function does a concatenate like:

```
np.concatenate((np.zeros(padshape, dtype=arr.dtype), arr),
                          axis=axis)
```

See `np.lib.arraypad.py` for details.

So for each nonzero pad amount it concatenates on a zeros block of the desired shape.

---

```
In [280]: x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
```

Your two `pad` versions:

```
In [281]: np.pad(x,((0,0),(1,0)), mode='constant')[:, :-1]
Out[281]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 5]])
In [282]:  np.pad(x,((0,0),(0,1)), mode='constant')[:, 1:]
Out[282]: 
array([[2, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 0]])
```

The direct `insert` equivalents:

```
In [283]: res = np.zeros_like(x)
In [284]: res[:,1:] = x[:,:-1]
In [285]: res
Out[285]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 5]])
In [286]: res = np.zeros_like(x)
In [287]: res[:,:-1] = x[:,1:]
In [288]: res
Out[288]: 
array([[2, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 0]])
```

You can do the same thing on the first axis.  The general expression is

```
res = np.zeros_like(x)
idx1 = (slice(...), slice(...))
idx2 = (slice(...), slice(...))
res[idx1] = x[idx2]
```

where the `idx` tuples depend on the roll axis and direction.

e.g.

```
idx1 = (slice(None), slice(1,None))
idx2 = (slice(None), slice(None,-1))
```

With 2 axes and 2 directions, that's 4 pairs.